# Typescript selective Picking with "renaming safety"

Tags: typescript

I currently have this code which is working fine:

```
export interface IReq {
    timestamp: number;
};

export interface ITrack extends IReq {
    id: number;
};

const track: Pick<ITrack, 'id'> = {
    id: 1
}
```

If id field from ITrack interface gets renamed we get a compiler error from tsc which is fine, but I would like to have the 'id' itself to be modified as well

Is there any way typescript could detect this kind of change?

Comment: Don't think this is possible

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TitianCernicova-Dragomir do you know any way to force only filling some fields of a child interface without using Pick<T> in a "renaming safe " way?

Comment: You can use `Partial<T>` to make all fields optional but event that will not be fully renaming safe, If you rename a field, the object literals will not get reanmed as far as I know

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The whole point of what I was trying to do was to decouple ITrack from IReq, and this can be done with a simple intersection type:

```
type TTrackReq = IReq & ITrack
```

By doing this we no longer need to extend from IReq and use only the attributes from ITrack, very interesting